# My Depth First Search function seems not to return list of visited nodes i need to Visualize on front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am writing my own visualizer based on this tutorial here https://github.com/clementmihailescu/Pathfinding-Visualizer-Tutorial,
I created a depth-first algorithm based on the javascript example in the Oreilly Book, data structures, and algorithms, example below here

```
    function dfs(v) {
        this.marked[v] = true;
        // if statement for print is not required
        if (this.adj[v] != undefined)
            print("Visited vertex: " + v);
        for each(var w in this.adj[v]) {
            if (!this.marked[w]) {
                this.dfs(w);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my implementation of the algorithm in my own react app is below here, the **grid** parameter is simply a 2-dimensional array of nodes, the **closestNode** being the start node to begin from, and the **finishNode** is the node to cancel the operation once reached, **visitedNodesInOrder** is an array to kept track of nodes being visited

```
export function startDfs(grid, closestNode, finishNode, visitedNodesInOrder) {
  // console.log(closestNode);
  closestNode.isVisited = true;
  if (closestNode !== undefined) {
    visitedNodesInOrder.push(closestNode);
  }

  var unvisitedNeighbors = getUnvisitedNeighbors(closestNode, grid);

  for (var x = 0; x < unvisitedNeighbors.length; x++) {
    if (!unvisitedNeighbors[x].isVisited) {
      if (unvisitedNeighbors[x].isWall) {
        continue;
      }
      if (unvisitedNeighbors[x] === finishNode) {
        return visitedNodesInOrder; // RETURN VISITED NODES HERE
      }
      startDfs(grid, unvisitedNeighbors[x], finishNode, visitedNodesInOrder);
    }
  }
}



function getUnvisitedNeighbors(node, grid) {
  const neighbors = [];
  const {col, row} = node;
  if (row > 0) neighbors.push(grid[row - 1][col]);
  if (row < grid.length - 1) neighbors.push(grid[row + 1][col]);
  if (col > 0) neighbors.push(grid[row][col - 1]);
  if (col < grid[0].length - 1) neighbors.push(grid[row][col + 1]);
  return neighbors.filter(neighbor => !neighbor.isVisited);
}
```

My final intention is to collect the **visitedNodesInOrder** array and animate the list of nodes on the grid i created on the front end, the 2D array is an exact reflection of the grid i made on the front end using a map function to map the original 2D List with nodes to  an HTML, CSS DOM layout, my final implementation that's giving me an error is below

```
 visualizeDijkstra() {
    var nodesInShortestPathOrder = [];
    var visitedNodesInOrder = [];
    const {grid} = this.state;
    const startNode = grid[START_NODE_ROW][START_NODE_COL];
    const finishNode = grid[FINISH_NODE_ROW][FINISH_NODE_COL];
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    visitedNodesInOrder = startDfs(
      grid,
      startNode,
      finishNode,
      visitedNodesInOrder,
    );
    console.log(visitedNodesInOrder);
    boardToClear = visitedNodesInOrder;
    //nodesInShortestPathOrder = getNodesInShulortestPathOrder(finishNode);
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    elasped = stop - start;

    this.animateDijkstra2(visitedNodesInOrder);
  }
```

this is the error i am getting below, i don't understand what happened to the array

```
PathfindingVisualizer.jsx:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at PathfindingVisualizer.animateDijkstra2
```

Comment: `visitedNodesInOrder` returns `undefined` you didnt add a return statement, you just mutate the args in scope.

Comment: the return statement is on the second code block, also added a comment so it stands out, do you think that's still the problem

Comment: Actually its seems that `this.state.grid` is undefined, you can just log and find where you get the error...